# How do you pass constructor GET parameter across methods in a class? PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, function, methods

I'm basically trying to pass a GET value from the construct function to the insert_update function. I have stripped out a lot of the latter function. Also, if it's worth to note, this page is an include page.

```
class Updates {

function __construct(){
$owner = $this->get = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
$owner=$owner["member_id"];
echo $owner;
}


//Insert Update
public function Insert_Update() 
{
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `field` (foo) VALUES (N'$owner')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: i'm kinda confused. whats the $owner var for in the constructor? you want to fetch the member_id from get in the constructor and use it in the insert_update method?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: and inside the SQL query - do you want everything from post? or just the member_id ?

Comment: why not use $this->get['member_id'] in the insert_update?

Comment: Without the construct function you mean?

Comment: nono, keep the constructor, and in the insert_update use $this->get['member_id']

Comment: I borrowed Kurt's code and went with:
function __construct(){$this->owner=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["member_id"]);}
But in public function Insert_Update() I can't get the value back although I can echo it just fine in the construct function. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Updates {
  private $owner;
  function __construct(){
  $owner = $this->get = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
  $this->owner=$owner["member_id"];
  echo $this->owner;
  }


  //Insert Update
  public function Insert_Update() 
  {
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `field` (foo) VALUES (N'".$this->owner."')") or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you declared "owner" as class member ? I updated code in my answer, look at 2 line.

Comment: I copied and tried this but for some reason it just gives me a blank in the db.

Comment: But echo $this->owner; from constructor displays correct string ? can u show this echo ? try also add "echo $this->owner;" before sql query and check if there you have correct value.

Comment: echo $this->owner; from constructor displays correctly but inside the Insert_Update before the sql query, I can't get it to display using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `owner` a member of `Updates` and store it in `this->owner`.

Comment: How would I go about getting the get paramater without calling __construct?

Comment: You can't call `Insert_Update()` without calling `__construct()` first anyway.

Comment: How would I make it a member of Updates?

Comment: The other answers show you: `private $owners;` ... `$this->owners = $owners`.

Comment: So I should have it a member of both the construct and Insert_Update? I tried but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what a member is.  It applies to the class, not methods.  When you write to it and read from it in all methods, you need to refer to it as `$this->owners`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Updates {

    protected $owner;

    function __construct($myGetVariable)
           $this->owner = $myGetVariable;
    }

    //Insert Update
    public function Insert_Update() 
    {
           // you can access the variable by typing:
           echo $this->owner;
           $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `field` (foo) VALUES (N'".$this->owner."')") or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

*sorry had to edit a few times, copied and pasted incorrectly, and then I wanted to make it more clear.

Comment: So, using this: 

protected $owner;
function __construct($myGetVariable){
$this->owner = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
echo $this->owner;
   }


The SQL insert: {.$this->owner.} brings back an array, any thoughts on how to get the actual get value instead?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you pass to the constructor. In the example you provided, you seem to want to grab `$owner["member_id"]`, I simplified my example to get the point across a little clearer. For my example to work, you would instantiate the class by passing the variable you want. You could then do any cleansing of the value in the constructor. 

`$updates = new Updates($_GET["member_id"]);` 
Then cleanse the value in your constructor using whatever methods you'd like, such as `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: $this->owner = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET); - this line is responsible. array_map returns array, and you are assigning this returned array to the "owner" field.

Comment: Actually I rechecked it and the problem is the array itself is empty; I'm just getting an empty array in Insert_Update.